# Why 312 Avoiding?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, pattern-recognition, catalan-numbers, constraints

I have recently had the chance to attend a nice talk in Combinatorics, and once the speaker alluded to the famous 312-avoiding pattern problem, I was reminded of the following question I have had since I heard something about $312$-avoiding patterns for the first time:

Regarding the fact that D. E. Knuth, in "Art of computer Programming", proves for any arbitrary $\sigma \in \mathcal S_3$, the number of $\sigma$-avoiding permutations in $\mathcal S_n$ is given by the $n$-th Catalan number, and knowing that when different combinatorics are counted by the same Catalans, there exist bijections between their objects (which may not be trivial of course), I was wondering if there is any technical (convincing) reason that people still stick to $312$-avoiding patterns, rather than $\sigma$-avoiding patterns, where $\sigma \in \mathcal S_3$ is fixed.

Comment: They are [stack-realizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-sortable_permutation), which might be a technical reason although I'd guess it is more likely a historic relic now.

Comment: Dear Joffan, Thanks for your comment.
The connection between what you pointed out and what I asked for became clearer when I read the note that @Alex R. has mentioned in the following answer.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under the general notion of "pattern avoiding permutations," and the combinatorics of these can loosely be said to be inherited from *reduced-decomposition* structure for such permutations. For adjacent transpositions $s_i=(i,i+1)$, the generators $s_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n-1$ form a Coxeter group and generate $S_n$. Thus any permutation can be written as a minimal sequence of $s_i$'s. Example $312=s_2s_1$. It turns out that 312-avoiding permutations have very particular reduced-decomposition structure. [Take a look at pages 7 and up of this reference on $c$-sortable permutations.](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~nreadin/papers/FPSAC06slides.pdf)

Comment: Dear Alex R. Thanks for your answer and the reference.

I looked at the note and based on what I understand, for a special choice of the Coxeter element $c$, the $c$-sortable elements in $W= \mathcal S_n$ are $312$-avoiding elements, counted by $Cat(W)=Cat(n)$, which are in bijection with the noncrossing partitions of the cycle $c$, and consequently with $c$-clusters.

Comment: I certainly agree that these bijections are really nice. However, I still cannot fully understand why they don't discuss other pattern avoiding cases. May be since it is clear to them what is happening, but not completely to me.

For instance $231$-avoiding elements, which are another set of $c$-sortable elements for a different choice of $c$.
If we have those nice properties about $312$-avoiding elements, should not we also expect an nice interpretation of noncrossing partitions for other choices of $c$?

Comment: $312$-avoiding permutations also have a particularly nice description through [_insertion encoding_](http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_12/PDF/v12i1r47.pdf). That encoding was used e.g. to [show](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502504) that $1324$-avoiding permutations grow asymptotically faster than $1234$-avoiding permutations.